# In Column Bucking strength of 24' 3"x3" Hollow Aluminum Tube with .125" Wall thickness

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, structural-analysis

I am designing a Gin Pole to lift a 500# load. The pole will be  hollow Aluminum tube 24'x3"x3" and .125" wall thickness pinned at both ends. The pole will be at a 45 degree with the top secured with a horizontal 1/8" steel cable secured to a tree.
Thus vertical load cable and the horizontal support cable to the tree will be at right angle putting a pure compression load on the pole of 700#.
Will the Aluminum tube describe safely withstand such a compressive force in column without buckling ? If not is a a heavier wall thickness prescribed?

Comment: Are you sure of "pure" compression? the mounting will be perfectly centred so as to not cause any side load?

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike

Answer (score 1):

Euler buckling equation is{

$Pcr = \dfrac{\pi^2EI}{le^2}$

for 3x3x1/8 aluminimun tube,

$E = 10x10^6 psi, I = 1.78 in^4$

for a column with pinned ends, K = 1.0, conservatively use 1.2,

$Le = K*L = 1.2*24*12 = 346 in$

$Pcr = \dfrac{\pi^2*10^7*1.78}{346^2} = 1467 lbs > 500 lbs$

Yes, strengthwise it would work provided the end condiditions are as assumed, and there is only compressive stress on the pole. But instability caused by flexibility could cause problems.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get my diagram to display, and even with the 1.2 safety factor it's 2x the expected load.

Comment: 1.2 safety factor is for the potential defects in the material/tube. you shall watch out for incidental eccentricity which can introduce a bending moment. Otherwise, it will be fine under the load.